# Why my usb disk can't be mounted automatically on debian8?

Tags: mount

There are two usb disks,one named usb-A ,other named usb-B.
The fdisk -l info is as the following when to insert usb-A

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 195311615 195309568 93.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       195311616 292968447  97656832 46.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       292968448 390625279  97656832 46.6G  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda4       390627326 488396799  97769474 46.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       390627328 468944895  78317568 37.4G  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda6       468946944 488396799  19449856  9.3G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 1015.5 MiB, 1064828928 bytes, 2079744 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0d0c0b0a

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors    Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       63 2072384 2072322 1011.9M  6 FAT16
```

Now usb-A can be mounted as /media/debian8/CC1F-721E ,the files on usb-A can be read and write.

The fdisk -l info is as the following when to insert usb-B

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 195311615 195309568 93.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       195311616 292968447  97656832 46.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       292968448 390625279  97656832 46.6G  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda4       390627326 488396799  97769474 46.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       390627328 468944895  78317568 37.4G  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda6       468946944 488396799  19449856  9.3G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 14.9 GiB, 16005464064 bytes, 31260672 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Why usb-B can't be mounted automatically such as usb-A,the files on usb-B can't read and write?
How to make usb-B can be mounted automatically such as usb-A?

Comment: Difficult to tell. Need more information.  Look at the end of `/var/log/syslog` with `less`.  Look for "sda" and "sdb" and the name of the USB manufacturer.

Comment: It looks to me as if usb-B either doesn't have a partition table, or the partition table is corrupted.  Does it work OK in other machines?  Add the ouput of `file -s /dev/sdb` to your question.